# Can I delete SSOServer Logs? (VMware)

Tags: log-files, compression, vmware-server

I have a client that has a large amount of log files within the SSOServer Logs folder. I want to compress/delete these files so that it makes room. Will this affect VMware? Most are text docs but some look to be more impotent, but there in a log file.